# SQL: First_value function cannot be nested inside a LEAD function

Tags: sql, nested, window, amazon-redshift

As the title says, I have column created with a First_value function and then I have a LEAD function that uses the column created with the First_value. I get the following error message:

> window function calls cannot be nested.

I understand what it is saying, but I don't know how to solve this.

Here is the SELECT statement

```
SELECT 
FIRST_VALUE(placed_at IGNORE NULLS) 
OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
AS purchased_at
,(condition1 > 0) AND (LEAD(purchased_at, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY timestamp) IS NULL)) 
AS has_led_to_purchase.
FROM table
```

Does anyone know how to execute this in another way so it works?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Amazon Redshift - Generic SQL would answer your question?

Comment: The obvious solution would be to use a subquery. But if you post some sample data and desired output, one could at least attempt to see if there is a better alternative